# Deezer JS SDK with Android & iOS devices

Tags: deezer

Does the Deezer JS SDK player work on iOS devices (does it have a HTML5 fallback?) or only on devices that have Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS SDK is indeed based on Flash for full track streaming. EDIT Only the widget player has an HTML5 fallback but only with 30 seconds previews (that you have directly from the API as well) - which is not available in the JS SDK.

Comment: Ok, then it goes as the documentation says. 30 seconds is enough for my needs. Thank you!